# R dynlm package - Choosing the optimal lag number

Tags: r, time-series

I am wondering if there is a way to choose the optimal number of the lags in the dynlm package given a criterion such as AIC.

For example, I have the following equations:

```
 fit = dynlm(y ~  L(y,1)+ L(x,1)

 fit = dynlm(y ~  L(y,1)+ L(x,1)+ L(x,2)         

 fit = dynlm(y ~  L(y,1)+ L(x,1)+ L(x,2)+ L(x,3)

 fit = dynlm(y ~  L(y,1)+ L(x,1)+ L(x,2)+  L(x,3)+ L(x,4))
```

Do I have to create  a do loop and generate which equation and pull the AIC? Anyone is familiar with an automatic way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compare the AIC of two models they must have the same response but that is not the case in your situation because adding a lag will reduce the set of y's that are fit.

The dyn package has an `anova.dyn` method which compares lagged models created by that package automatically subsetting the longer series to ensure that the series can  be validly compared.